# Azure Auth - Forcing a complete logout with mobileServicesClient

Tags: android, azure, authentication

I am working on an android application. I want to be able to force a complete logout and have it so when I call login again the user is actually forced to type in their username and password. I know this is easily possible with the google API but I would like to use the built in support that azure offers.

Currently, calling mclient.logout() or getting a new instance of mclient doesn't seem to work (even with all tokens deleted). It still somehow seems to remember what account I choose the first time when I call mclient.login because **the google window pops up but then immediately closes without displaying anything and it automatically logs into the account i logged into the first time.** I want to force the user to type in their google info after a logout and a log back in.

**The only way I have found so far to force the user to retype the info is to delete the entire application data/cache.**

Then when I call mclient.login() again the user is forced to retype their info. However, this is not ideal because I am storing other things in the cache that i don't want to be deleting every time.

Can somebody point me in the right direction or tell me what exact files/folders i need to be deleting from the cache to prevent azure/google from trying to use the same account that was used the first time.

**Why is this happening? It seems like calling logout() and then login() again should force a full relog but it does not** Azure/google is doing something in the background that is somehow remembering what account I used even with all login tokens removed and a completely new instance of mclient

Answer (score 0):

`mclient.login()` doesn't work because the chrome browser has store the login info in cookies, and the next time you `login` via the authentication provider, the browser will automatically read the cookies and finish the login flow.

Please try the following code to remove the cookie when logout:

```
    mClient.logout();
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```